# Subset Dataframe Conditionally

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

*Any advice on a more pythonic way to group is also appreciated*

I have a dataframe "golfdf" that is comprised of two columns, "Teams" and "Clubs".

```
           Teams   Clubs
0          Aiden   Right
1          Alexa   Right
2          Alina   NaN
3          Allison Right
4          Amity   Right
5          Antoine NaN
6          Ben     NaN
...
35         Connor  Right
```

I am trying to shuffle the dataframe into a random order and then break the dataframe into groups of four where there are a  minimum of two and a maximum of three NaN values per group.

I shuffle using:

```
gdf = golfdf.sample(frac=1)
```

And then split into groups of four using:

```
n = int(len(gdf)/9)
groups_n = np.cumsum([0, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, len(gdf)-(8*n)])
d = {}
for i in range(9):
    d[i+1] = gdf.iloc[groups_n[i]:groups_n[i+1]]
```

The output is as expected:

```
     Teams Clubs
8    Breanne NaN
5    Antoine NaN
27   Noah    NaN
16   Ellen  Left
     Teams Clubs
20   Helen   NaN
22   Keegan  NaN
28   Payton  NaN
32   Sean    NaN
...
```

But I am not sure how to add a condition specifying the constraints. Please let me know if I've left out any relevant information.

Thanks!

Comment: What if it is not possible to have 2-3 `NaN` in a group?

Comment: Thanks, should have clarified. As many groups as possible with the condition, the rest would just be the remainder I suppose? Sorry if this is poor wording.